# what does so many hexadecimal values mean to print a string in the assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, ascii, nasm, disassembly

I'm new to the assembly world and I study converting code in C to better understand the logic. I use objconv to do the conversion and I use Windows. I converted the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int vector[5] = {2, 6, 8, 9, 4};
    int aux = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        aux = aux + vector[i];
    }

    printf("The summation of array is: %d", aux);
}
```

The generated assembly code was:

```
global _main: 

extern _printf                                          
extern ___main                                          


SECTION .text                            

.text:  ; Local function

_main:
        push    ebp                                     
        mov     ebp, esp                                
        and     esp, 0FFFFFFF0H                        
        sub     esp, 48                                 
        call    ___main                                
        mov     dword [esp+14H], 2                      
        mov     dword [esp+18H], 6                      
        mov     dword [esp+1CH], 8                      
        mov     dword [esp+20H], 9                      
        mov     dword [esp+24H], 4                      
        mov     dword [esp+2CH], 0                     
        mov     dword [esp+28H], 0                     
        jmp     ?_002                                  

?_001:  mov     eax, dword [esp+28H]                   
        mov     eax, dword [esp+eax*4+14H]             
        add     dword [esp+2CH], eax                   
        add     dword [esp+28H], 1                     
?_002:  cmp     dword [esp+28H], 4                     
        jle     ?_001                                  
        mov     eax, dword [esp+2CH]                   
        mov     dword [esp+4H], eax                    
        mov     dword [esp], ?_003                     
        call    _printf                                
        mov     eax, 0                                  
        leave                                          
        ret                                           

        nop                                            


SECTION .data                        


SECTION .bss                        


SECTION .rdata                    

?_003:                                                  ; byte
        db 54H, 68H, 65H, 20H, 73H, 75H, 6DH, 6DH       ; 0000 _ The summ
        db 61H, 74H, 69H, 6FH, 6EH, 20H, 6FH, 66H       ; 0008 _ ation of
        db 20H, 61H, 72H, 72H, 61H, 79H, 20H, 69H       ; 0010 _  array i
        db 73H, 3AH, 20H, 25H, 64H, 00H, 00H, 00H       ; 0018 _ s: %d...
```

As you can see, C's printf is representing the assembly at label ?_003. What exactly would all this data be? Is it possible to simplify this output?

Comment: These are the ASCII codes of the characters that make up the string.  The comment on the right hand side shows you what characters these are (`.` is also used for an unprintable character).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hexadecimal block at the label `?_003` is just the representation of the C string

> "The summation of array is: %d"

You can see an ASCII translation on the right side after the comment char `;`: the number is the relative address, the underscore a delimiter, and the chars are part of the string.

```
db 54H, 68H, 65H, 20H, 73H, 75H, 6DH, 6DH       ; 0000 _ The summ
db 61H, 74H, 69H, 6FH, 6EH, 20H, 6FH, 66H       ; 0008 _ ation of
db 20H, 61H, 72H, 72H, 61H, 79H, 20H, 69H       ; 0010 _  array i
db 73H, 3AH, 20H, 25H, 64H, 00H, 00H, 00H       ; 0018 _ s: %d...
```

An equivalent in (NASM) assembly that isn't created automatically (like by objconv) would be

```
outStr: db "The summation of array is: %d",0
```

Comment: That output you provided also works the same way. Incredible! Can you pass me a documentation that talks about 'outSrt' ?

Comment: Of course. The standard resource is the [website of NASM](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html), but I didn't mention it, because it might be too much for a beginner. A basic tutorial is IMHO better and covers the relevant topics for this question: A [tutorial with graphic explanations](https://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/nasmtutorial/) that I googled yesterday. It is for x86_64 on Linux (So the system calls differ), but it explains NASM programs in general.